# What does Google Analytics show if a user opts out of GA tracking

Tags: google-analytics

What can you see if a user opts out of Google Analytics tracking using the browser plugin, can you see that they came, but not much else ie. they show up as a direct visitor, or do they not show up at all (although you can always see them in the server logs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data will not be reported to you (they do not show up at all).

In fact you can set this up programmatically as well - [Tracking Basics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#disable). When you do execute the disable tracking command or if the visitor has a disabled Javascript or disabled tracking, then GA will not report that visit.